# SQL query performance using CTE vs WHILE loop in very large table

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best performing query given the scenario below.

The following table is very large, over 5 million rows. Every day, a few loads occur although exactly how many times varies. Each load is identified by load_id (a part of clustered index) and load_datetimestamp is time stamp applicable to that load. Each load inserts about 30,000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE [VeryLargeTable](
        [load_id]               [int]           NOT NULL, 
        [acct_cd]               [varchar](20)   NOT NULL,
        [acct_num]              [varchar](255)  NULL,
        [prod_id]               [varchar](50)   NOT NULL,
        [domestic_foreign_cd]   [varchar](3)    NOT NULL,
        [vendor_prod_id]        [varchar](15)   NULL,
        [prod_name]             [varchar](100)  NULL,
        [currency_cd]           [varchar](3)    NULL,
        [total_Qty]             [int]           NULL,
        [mkt_price]             [float]         NULL,
        [load_datetimestamp]    [datetime]      NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_VeryLargeTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (       
        [load_id] ASC, 
        [acct_cd] ASC, 
        [prod_id] ASC,
        [domestic_foreign_cd] ASC )
)
```

On any given evening, I would like to get all the rows from today's FIRST load. Query must be as performant as possible given above DDL. Obviously, you don't want to start out with something like "WHERE datediff(day,load_datetimestamp,getDate())=0" on the entire table.

I wrote these 2 queries. Is any one better than the other? I know that both return the same result. Can you suggest even a better one than either one of these 2?

**Query 1**

```
With 
T1 as (select
    load_id,
    load_datetimestamp
    from dbo.VeryLargeTable
    group by 
    load_id,load_datetimestamp),
T2 as (select
    load_id,
    load_datetimestamp
    from T1
    where
    datediff(day,load_datetimestamp,getDate())=0),
T3 as (select min(load_id) as loadID from T2)

select * from dbo.VeryLargeTable
where load_id = (select loadID from T3)
```

**Query 2**

```
declare @found tinyint;
declare @loadID int;
declare @dateTimeStamp datetime;

-- Get max value of load id
select @loadID = max(load_id) from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable];

-- Keep looping until previous day is found or minimum load_id is reached
set @found = 0;
WHILE (@found=0)
    BEGIN
        select @dateTimeStamp = load_datetimestamp from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable] where load_id=@loadID;
        if (@loadID=0) SET @found=1
        else 
            BEGIN
                if (DATEPART(day, @dateTimeStamp) = DATEPART(day, GetDate())) SET @loadID = @loadID - 1;
                else SET @found=1;              
            END
    END

SELECT * from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable] where load_id=(@loadID + 1);
```

Comment: At the very least make this sargeable: `datediff(day,load_datetimestamp,getDate())=0)`. Is there a way to rewrite it so that the load_datetimestamp does not have a function around it? i.e. `load_datetimestamp >= SELECT CAST(CAST(getDate() as DATE) As DATETIME)` makes `load_datetimestamp` sargeable and I believe implements the same logic.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Good point about sargability. It's worth pointing out that there needs to be an index on the column first.

Comment: That's correct. It's just a good habit to get into. Im hoping the OP will do some research on sargability

Comment: Thanks, I will change the datediff to one you suggested so when indexing is applied to load_datetimestamp, query will be faster without further code change. However, at this point, I'm still trying to get the fastest performing query given above DDL. Seems like shree.pat18 below has the best answer thus far and Joel Coehoorn is backing it up by saying the query is faster than "while" loop implementation above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) As it was mentioned in the comments don't use expression like `datediff(day,load_datetimestamp,getDate())=0)`. This expression can't use index on column `load_datetimestamp`.

Use `load_datetimestamp >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)`.

2) Create an index on column `load_datetimestamp`.

3) Find the first row that was loaded today and take `load_id` from it:

```
SELECT TOP(1) load_id
FROM dbo.VeryLargeTable
WHERE load_datetimestamp >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
ORDER BY load_datetimestamp
```

This query should be an instant seek of the index on `load_datetimestamp`. Check the execution plan.

4) Create an index on `load_id` column.

5) Use the found `load_id` to return all rows for that load:

```
WITH
CTE_FirstLoad
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) load_id
    FROM dbo.VeryLargeTable
    WHERE load_datetimestamp >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
    ORDER BY load_datetimestamp
)
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.VeryLargeTable
WHERE load_id IN (SELECT load_id FROM CTE_FirstLoad)
;
```

This should use the index on `load_id`.

I've edited the answer and put `IN` instead of `=` in the last `WHERE`. With `IN` the query will work even if there were no loads for today at all. With `=` most likely there would be an error.

### Edit

Now we know that you can't create new indexes on this table. And we know that the number of loads per day is small (around 5).

With this limitation it may well be that your second query with the explicit loop would be the fastest. In any case, you have to try all suggestions on the real system and measure their performance.

Can we assume that each load starts and ends during the same day? In other words, for each `load_id` the date of the `load_datetimestamp` is the same?

Then, you can try few tweaks to your loop. They may not change the performance much or at all, but you have to measure.

instead of:

```
select @loadID = max(load_id) from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable];
```

try:

```
SET @loadID = 
    (select TOP(1) load_id from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable] ORDER BY load_id DESC);
```

in the same fashion inside the loop (I doubt that the current line actually works, because you have many rows for the same `load_id`) instead of:

```
select @dateTimeStamp = load_datetimestamp from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable] where load_id=@loadID;
```

try:

```
SET @dateTimeStamp = 
    (select TOP(1) load_datetimestamp from [dbo].[VeryLargeTable] where load_id=@loadID);
```

### If you are allowed to create another table

I assume that load IDs increase with time, i.e. load with `ID=N` has `load_datetimestamp` less than load with `ID=N+1`.

Create a separate table `Loads` with column: `load_id` with primary unique clustered index on `load_id`.

This table would contain one row for the last `load_id` for each day. It would be much smaller than the main table.

The purpose of this table is to quickly find the "first load_id for today" instead of scanning the large table.

Every evening when you run your report this small `Loads` table would contain rows for loads from previous days, but not from today.

Can you say, that at the time when you run your report in the evening all loading has finished for the day? If yes:

Get the last load from previous days from the small table:

```
SET @PrevLoadID = 
(SELECT TOP(1) load_id FROM Loads ORDER BY load_id DESC)
```

Get the first load for today from the large table:

```
SET @TodayFirstLoadID = 
(SELECT TOP(1) load_id 
FROM VeryLargeTable 
WHERE VeryLargeTable.load_id >  @PrevLoadID
ORDER BY load_id ASC)
```

Get the last load for today from the large table:

```
SET @TodayLastLoadID = 
(SELECT TOP(1) load_id 
FROM VeryLargeTable 
ORDER BY load_id DESC)
```

`INSERT` the `@TodayLastLoadID` into `Loads`.

Use `@TodayFirstLoadID` to run your main report:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VeryLargeTable 
WHERE load_id = @TodayFirstLoadID
```

Comment: Vladimir, I should have been clearer - no indexing allowed at this point on load_datetimestamp. My goal is to generate the fastest query given the above DDL. Note that load_id is already in clustered index so maybe you can suggest a query that will take advantage of this fact.

Comment: @SamDevx, you definitely should have clearly stated in the question that you can't create indexes. I'm curious, why do you have such limitation? Can you create a helper table? See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir for your updated answer. Your assumption is correct i.e. each load occurs on same day so there are no two different load_datetimestamp for a given load_id. Your suggestion for adding a new table to hold each day's last load_id is good. That, along with the suggestion for adding non-clustered index on load_datetimestamp are something I will pursue with the DBAs in near future. For now, as you point out correctly, I will compare the execution plans using the CTE-query suggested by shree.pat18 versus the loop-query I wrote originally with your changes. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @SamDevx, If you can add the helper table it is likely to have the best performance, even if you add an index on  load_datetimestamp later. But, of course, these are only guesses. You really need to measure all variants on your system. I mean, not just look at the execution plans, but actually run the queries and time them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 3 CTEs here. You can replace the first 2 CTEs by simply selecting all distinct combinations of Load ID and Load DateTimeStamp which satisfy the filter condition. Then, you can get rid of the 3rd CTE by moving that check directly to the subquery in your final select. The resulting query would look like this:

```
;With 
T2 as 
(select distinct
 load_id,
 load_datetimestamp
 from dbo.VeryLargeTable
 where datediff(day,load_datetimestamp,getDate())=0)

select * from dbo.VeryLargeTable
where load_id = (select min(load_ID) from T2)
```

Comment: And this will almost certainly trump any kind of loop in a big way.

Comment: Joel, is the while loop really that bad? The number of loads on any given day will not be greater than 5 (sorry I should have mentioned that earlier), so at most the "while" loop above will loop for 5 times. Will shree.pat18's query still run faster than the while loop implementation?

Comment: @SamDevx For something like that, where it only runs a few times per day and only takes a few seconds, it might be okay, but it's not the approach you want to take by default on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check it on your execution plan but if I were you I would use a temp table instead of using 3 table expressions and joining it with my original table.

Also as you mentioned earlier better not to use functions in your `WHERE` clause. Instead you can use `date BETWEEN start AND end`